# Simplification or alternative for this Scala pattern match

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, pattern-matching

I have implemented a Play! 2 QueryStringBindable in Scala for a Range type. A Range consists of either a min or max value or both (of type Float). In my QueryBindable implementation I use the internalBinder to convert the two possible parameters min  and max to Option[Either[String, Float]], combine them in a tuple, do a pattern match over this and finally return an Option[Either[String, Range]]. This works but as you can see in the code below the pattern match is very verbose. Is there a more concise way of doing this in Scala?
Maybe leverage higher order functions somehow to get the same result structure back?

```
import play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable

case class Range(min: Option[Float], max: Option[Float])

object Range {

implicit def rangeQueryStringBindable(implicit intBinder: QueryStringBindable[Float]) = new QueryStringBindable[Range] {

    override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Range]] = {

      val minOpt = intBinder.bind("min", params)
      val maxOpt = intBinder.bind("max", params)
      (minOpt, maxOpt) match {
        case (None, None) => None
        case (Some(Right(min)), Some(Right(max))) => Some(Right(Range(Some(min), Some(max))))
        case (None, Some(Right(max))) => Some(Right(Range(None, Some(max))))
        case (Some(Right(min)), None) => Some(Right(Range(Some(min), None)))
        case (Some(Left(minError)), Some(Left(maxError))) => Some(Left(minError))
        case (Some(Left(minError)), None) => Some(Left(minError))
        case (None, Some(Left(maxError))) => Some(Left(maxError))
        case (Some(Right(_)), Some(Left(maxError))) => Some(Left(maxError))
        case (Some(Left(minError)), Some(Right(_))) => Some(Left(minError))
      }
    }

    override def unbind(key: String, range: Range): String = {
      (range.min, range.max) match {
        case (Some(min), Some(max)) => intBinder.unbind("min", min) + "&" + intBinder.unbind("max", max)
        case (Some(min), None) => intBinder.unbind("min", min)
        case (None, Some(max)) => intBinder.unbind("max", max)
        case (None, None) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range without values makes no sense")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(minOpt,maxOpt) match {
  case (None,None) => None
  case (Some(Left(m)),_) => Some(Left(m))
  case (_,Some(Left(m))) => Some(Left(m))
  case (_,_) => Some(Right(Range(minOpt.map(_.right.get),maxOpt.map(_.right.get))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks indeed much more concise!

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of functions to convert an `Option[Either[Error, A]]` to `Either[Error, Option[A]]` you can end up with something a bit cleaner in my view. I also recommend renaming Range since it conflicts with a class with the same name in `scala.collections.immutable`.

```
import play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable

case class RealRange(min: Option[Float], max: Option[Float])

object BindingEitherUtils {
  implicit class OptionWithEitherFlatten[A, B](value: Option[Either[A, B]]) {
    def flattenRight: Either[A, Option[B]] = {
      value.map { either =>
        either.right.map{ right => Some(right) }
      }.getOrElse{ Right(None) }
    }
  }

  implicit class EitherWithUnflatten[A, B](value: Either[A, Option[B]]) {
    def unflattenRight: Option[Either[A, B]] = {
      value.fold(left => Some(Left(left)), _.map{ right => Right(right) })
    }
  }
}

object RealRange {
  import BindingEitherUtils._

  val minError = "Invalid minimum value for RealRange"
  val maxError = "Invalid maximum value for RealRange"

  implicit def rangeQueryStringBindable(implicit floatBinder: QueryStringBindable[Float]) = new QueryStringBindable[RealRange] {
    override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, RealRange]] = {
      val minOpt = floatBinder.bind("min", params).flattenRight
      val maxOpt = floatBinder.bind("max", params).flattenRight

      minOpt.left.map{ _ => minError }.right.flatMap { min =>
        maxOpt.left.map{ _ => maxError }.right.flatMap { max =>
          (min, max) match {
            case (None, None ) =>
              Right(None)
            case (Some(minVal), Some(maxVal)) if minVal > maxVal =>
              Left("Minimum value is larger than maximum value")
            case _ =>
              Right(Some(RealRange(min, max)))
          }
        }
      }.unflattenRight
    }

    override def unbind(key: String, range: RealRange): String = {
      (range.min, range.max) match {
        case (Some(min), Some(max)) => floatBinder.unbind("min", min) + "&" + floatBinder.unbind("max", max)
        case (Some(min), None) => floatBinder.unbind("min", min)
        case (None, Some(max)) => floatBinder.unbind("max", max)
        case (None, None) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("RealRange without values makes no sense")
      }
    }
  }

  def test(): Unit = {
    val binder = rangeQueryStringBindable

    Seq[(String, String)](
      ("10", "20"),
      ("10", null),
      (null, "10"),
      (null, null),
      ("asd", "asd"),
      ("10", "asd"),
      ("asd", "10"),
      ("asd", null),
      (null, "asd"),
      ("20", "10")
    ).foreach{ case (min, max) =>
      val params = Seq(
        Option(min).map{ m => "min" -> Seq(m) },
        Option(max).map{ m => "max" -> Seq(m) }
      ).flatten.toMap

      val result = binder.bind("", params)

      println(s"$params => $result" )
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in:

```
Map(min -> List(10), max -> List(20)) =>
  Some(Right(RealRange(Some(10.0),Some(20.0))))
Map(min -> List(10)) =>
  Some(Right(RealRange(Some(10.0),None)))
Map(max -> List(10)) =>
  Some(Right(RealRange(None,Some(10.0))))
Map() =>
  None
Map(min -> List(asd), max -> List(asd)) =>
  Some(Left(Invalid minimum value for RealRange))
Map(min -> List(10), max -> List(asd)) =>
  Some(Left(Invalid maximum value for RealRange))
Map(min -> List(asd), max -> List(10)) =>
  Some(Left(Invalid minimum value for RealRange))
Map(min -> List(asd)) =>
  Some(Left(Invalid minimum value for RealRange))
Map(max -> List(asd)) =>
  Some(Left(Invalid maximum value for RealRange))
Map(min -> List(20), max -> List(10)) =>
  Some(Left(Minimum value is larger than maximum value))
```

Comment: Interesting approach but in terms of readability i prefer the solution from @Marth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be simplified.

For the `bind` method you can place a few wildcards, when you have errors to simplify it. That way you only have 4 permutations for the `Range` assembly logic. I wouldn't do too much magic here as it would complicate understanding your code.

```
override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Range]] = {

  val minOpt = intBinder.bind("min", params)
  val maxOpt = intBinder.bind("max", params)

  (minOpt, maxOpt) match {
    case (None, None) => None
    case (Some(Right(min)), Some(Right(max))) => Some(Right(Range(Some(min), Some(max))))
    case (None, Some(Right(max))) => Some(Right(Range(None, Some(max))))
    case (Some(Right(min)), None) => Some(Right(Range(Some(min), None)))
    // Error handling
    case (Some(Left(minError)), _) => Some(Left(minError))
    case (_, Some(Left(maxError))) => Some(Left(maxError))
  }
}
```

For the unbind I would use a different approach, by utilizing `Option`'s map function and then combining them into a `Iterable` you can call `mkString` and it will do nothing for 1 string and append a `&` if there are two strings. The code example has types, so you can understand easier.

```
def unbind(key: String, range: Range): String = {
  val minString: Option[String] = range.min.map(min => intBinder.unbind("min", min))
  val maxString: Option[String] = range.max.map(max => intBinder.unbind("max", max))
  val strings: Iterable[String] = minString ++ maxString
  strings match {
    case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range without values makes no sense")
    case _ => strings.mkString("&")
  }
}
```

And if you're into short code:

```
def unbind(key: String, range: Range): String = {
  val minString = range.min.map(min => intBinder.unbind("min", min))
  val maxString = range.max.map(max => intBinder.unbind("max", max))
  minString ++ maxString match {
    case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range without values makes no sense")
    case strings => strings.mkString("&")
  }
}
```

Comment: Like your improved version of "unbind"! But for the "bind" part the solution from @Marth is even shorter and saves 2 more cases.

Comment: Yep, I agree! Hadn't thought of that.